# Can I assign types to class properties in MATLAB?

Tags: oop, class, matlab

I'm new to using MATLAB as an object-oriented environment and I'm writing my first class to describe a network packet. A simple example would be the following

```
classdef Packet

    properties
        HeaderLength
        PayloadLength
        PacketType
    end

end
```

I would like to explicitly specify that `HeaderLength` and `PayloadLength` are both uint16's and `PacketType` is a string. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There exist an [undocumented syntax](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/defining-properties.html) to enforce property types:

```
classdef Packet
    properties
        HeaderLength@uint16
        PayloadLength@uint16 = uint16(0);
        PacketType@char
    end
end
```

If you try to set a property with the wrong type, you get an error:

```
>> p = Packet;
>> p.PacketType = 'tcp';
>> p.HeaderLength = 100;
While setting the 'HeaderLength' property of Packet:
Value must be 'uint16'.
```

As far as I can tell, this syntax support all primitive types like: `char, int32, double, struct, cell, ...`, in addition to any user-defined ones (just use any class name).

Note that setting the type as above seems to override any "set method" if any.

I just came across this syntax being used in an internal class in R2013a (`toolboxdir('matlab')\graphics\+graphics\+internal\+figfile\@FigFile\FigFile.m`), but it also worked in R2012a, probably older versions as well...

Comment: [Cross reference](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/setting-class-property-types)

Comment: @YairAltman: thanks again for posting a dedicated article on your blog

Comment: A very similar syntax (but with space instead of "@") is officially [supported](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/restrict-class-of-properties.html) since R2016a. While R2015b only works with "@"-syntax, R2016a supports both.

Comment: @Igor yes, I saw that in the latest [release notes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#bu5a6iv)! They finally added it as a supported feature. You should post a separate answer showing how to use it.

Answer (score 9):

The "[Restrict Property Values to Specific Classes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/restrict-class-of-properties.html)" feature is now officially supported [since R2016a](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#bu5a6iv). It works similarly the old undocumented syntax, described in [Amro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15992558/1032586).

```
classdef Packet
    properties
        HeaderLength uint16
        PayloadLength uint16 = uint16(0);
        PacketType char
    end
end
```

**Compatibility with previous versions**

R2016a supports both syntax options, I've noticed no differences between them. However, they both work slightly different from the "@"-based syntax in R2015b:

1. In R2015b, an object `myProp` of a class `MyPropClass2`, inherited from `MyPropClass1`, perfectly passes the "class restriction" check, and then is stored "as is". So, the whole thing works just like an explicit `isa(newPropVal,MyPropClass1)` check added to a property set method `MyPropClass1`
2. In case of R2016a "Restrict Property Values to Specific Classes" syntax, Matlab converts said object to the specified class. This would require an appropriate constructor for `MyPropClass1`, and means that `MyPropClass1` could not be `Abstract`.

Example:

```
classdef MyPropClass1       
   methods
       % The following method is only used in R2016a case
       function obj=MyPropClass1(val)            
       end
   end         
end

------------------------------------------------------------
classdef MyPropClass2 < MyPropClass1       
end

------------------------------------------------------------
classdef MyObjClass     
    properties
        someprop@MyPropClass1
    end   
end

------------------------------------------------------------
myObj = MyObjClass();
myObj.someprop = MyPropClass2;

% The following displays "MyPropClass1" in R2016a, and "MyPropClass2" in R2015b
disp(class(myObj.someprop));
```

**Compatibility with class hierarchies**

In both R2016a and R2015b, the "Restrict Property Values to Specific Classes" qualifiers could not be re-defined in nested classes. E.g. it is not possible to define something like:

```
classdef MyObjClass2 < MyObjClass  
    properties
        someprop@MyPropClass2
    end   
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Since it is not possible to explicitly specify types for variables in Matlab, you cannot do this when declaring properties.

However, you can define a set method which checks the class and either throws an error or converts the input to whatever you want.

For example

```
classdef myClass
   properties
      myProperty = uint16(23); %# specify default value using correct type
   end
   methods
      function obj = set.myProperty(obj,val)
         if ~isa(val,'uint16')
            error('only uint16 values allowed')
         end
         %# assign the value
         obj.myProperty = val;
      end
   end
end
```