# Matlab Object Oriented composition, aggregation

Tags: oop, matlab, uml, code-generation

i'm writing my first MATLAB O-O application and i'm confused about the implementation of compositions, aggregations and relationships in general.

My question is: how to implement an aggregation or an association one-to-many in matlab? Where i can take some examples?

Moreover, i'm using ArgoUml to design my application, is there any plugin to automatic code generation in matlab?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick example of class association. The scenario consists of a course that can have many students enrolled:

#### Student.m

```
classdef Student < handle
    properties
        name
    end
    methods
        function obj = Student(name)
            if nargin > 0
                obj.name = name;
            end
        end
        function delete(obj)
            fprintf('-- Student Destructor: %s\n',obj.name);
        end
    end
end
```

#### Course.m

```
classdef Course < handle
    properties
        name        %# course name
        std         %# cell array of students
    end
    properties(Access = private)
        lastIdx = 1;
    end
    methods
        function obj = Course(name, capacity)
            obj.name = name;
            obj.std = cell(capacity,1);
        end
        function addStudent(obj, std)
            if obj.lastIdx > numel(obj.std)
                fprintf(2, 'Sorry, class is full\n');
                return
            end
            obj.std{obj.lastIdx} = std;
            obj.lastIdx = obj.lastIdx + 1;
        end
        function printClassRoster(obj)
            fprintf('Course Name = %s\n', obj.name);
            fprintf('Enrolled = %d, Capacity = %d\n', ...
                obj.lastIdx-1, length(obj.std));
            for i=1:obj.lastIdx-1
                fprintf('ID = %d, Name = %s\n', i, obj.std{i}.name);
            end
        end
    end

end
```

And here is a code to test the above classes:

```
c = Course('CS101', 3);
for i=1:4
    name = sprintf('amro%d',i);
    fprintf('Adding student: %s\n', name)
    c.addStudent( Student(name) )
end

fprintf('\nClass Roster:\n=============\n')
c.printClassRoster()

fprintf('\nCleaning up:\n')
clear c
```

The output:

```
Adding student: amro1
Adding student: amro2
Adding student: amro3
Adding student: amro4
Sorry, class is full
-- Student Destructor: amro4

Class Roster:
=============
Course Name = CS101
Enrolled = 3, Capacity = 3
ID = 1, Name = amro1
ID = 2, Name = amro2
ID = 3, Name = amro3

Cleaning up:
-- Student Destructor: amro1
-- Student Destructor: amro2
-- Student Destructor: amro3
```

Comment: Perfect!! But i cannot understand the "destruction" process... if a delete a course c, why all student are deleted? in this way we have a composition... how to implement an aggregation?

Comment: @fdaniii: Sorry my OOP concepts were a bit rusty, but I was thinking of association in the general sense.. Anyways MATLAB uses reference counting, i.e if another reference to the underlying data still exists, the memory will not be freed. So if you don't want the students objects life-cycle to be dependent on the course object, you could store the created objects in the main function, then pass the handle to the `addStudent` method: `s = cell(4,1); for i=1:4, s{i} = Student('...'); c.addStudent(s{i}); end`. That way they persist when the course object is destructed.

Comment: You can use the `@` symbol to define the type of a property, in this example `std@Student`. The association with `Class Student` works without it, but with the `@` it is enforced and documented in the code. See Amros [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192048/can-i-assign-types-to-class-properties-in-matlab/15992558#15992558).

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at [Object-Oriented Programming in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.ch/discovery/object-oriented-programming.html) and in the documentation refer to [Object-Oriented Programming](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/ug_intropage.html).

I suggest to have a closer look [Value or Handle Class — Which to Use](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_oop/which-kind-of-class-to-use.html)
. To make it short, handle classes let you pass references around whereas value classes are always a copy of the original object.

I'd be surprised to find a plugin for ArgoUml, as MATLAB is mainly used by engineers and not software developers.

Comment: But i cannot find how to implement an association. I'm looking for an example if possible. Do you know where i can take one?