# Matlab OOP type checking for abstract superclass

Tags: matlab, oop

In many programming languages such as e.g. C# you can supply the type of arguments to a class constructor.

Something like:

```
MyConstructor(IDependencyClass)
```

Here, 'IDependencyClass' is an interface. This allows you to use dependency injection and loose coupling of components.

Matlab also has support for OOP and even though it is not strongly typed nor does it offer a concept such as class interfaces (AFAIK), I naively thought I would be able to use any of the following variations:

```
classdef (Abstract) AbsClass 
   ...
end
```

Next, in any class where there would be a dependency on AbClass I would either create a private property like so:

```
properties (Access = private)

    % The DataModule type is restricted AbsClass.
    DataModule Core.Modularity.AbsBase

end
```

This property could then be set at construction.

Alternatively, I could do a check in the constructor using something like:

`isa(input argument, 'Core.Modularity.AbsBase')`

Oddly enough, Matlab doesn't want to play ball, throwing up an error:

```
Abstract classes cannot be instantiated.  
Class 'Core.Modularity.AbsClass' defines abstract methods and/or properties
```

To me, that is a bit strange... apparently the type checking mechanisms of Matlab want to create an instance of the abstract class, which obviously is not possible.

Not being able to do this however is a huge drawback if you want to design a proper application of medium to high complexity.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

Rather silly, but it turns out that the 'isa()' approach does work but I indeed omitted the '

Although it is still a bit strange that restricting the class of Properties approach does not work:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/restrict-class-of-properties.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that if you want to restrict the class of a given property, MATLAB needs to create a default empty value for that property (of that class) and therefore the `empty` method must be able to be successfully called (`Core.Modularity.AbsClass.empty()`), but since it's an abstract class, this isn't possible.

Trying to do so, results in this error:

> When restricting the class of a property value, the property must be restricted
>   to a concrete class.
>   Replace abstract class 'Core.Modularity.AbsBase' in the definition of property 'DataModule' in
>   class 'MyClass'.

Now *technically* [you can use the old (and undocumented) syntax for restricting the class of a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192048/can-i-assign-types-to-class-properties-in-matlab/15992558#15992558) and apparently it works

```
classdef MyClass
    properties
        DataModule@Core.Modularity.AbsBase
    end
end
```

Strangely, if we examine `DataModule`, it is in fact a `0 x 0` instance of `Core.Modularity.AbsClass`.

```
inst = MyClass()
class(inst.DataModule)
%   Core.Modularity.AbsClass

size(inst.DataModule)
%   0   0
```

Another option is to use `isa` to enforce the type of a given input argument. Also it's important to note that the second input to `isa` must be a string so that you don't have the same issue as above with MATLAB trying to instantiate an abstract class.

```
classdef MyClass < handle
    methods
        function self = MyClass(cls)
            disp(isa(cls, 'Core.Modularity.AbsClass'))
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: The reason I need to be able to do this is because it is a basic aspect of [modular application development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) or [interface based programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface-based_programming). I need to ensure that whatever I inject into my consuming class will offer the required functionality, hence I ideally design the consuming class to expect a specific dependency...

Comment: By the way, enforcing an argument to be of a certain base type is exactly what I want to do...

Comment: @Kris Then use `isa` like I mentioned to do that.

Comment: @Kris I'm going to assume that you passed a `Core.Modularity.AbsClass` rather than the *string* `'Core.Modularity.AbsClass'`

Comment: Embarrasingly, that indeed seems to have been the case. I don't know what I mis-typed earlier, I could have sworn I entered it correctly :s

Comment: Oddly enough, there is this on the Matlab website: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/restrict-class-of-properties.html

Comment: @Kris I've updated with some more information as well as a workaround

Comment: Cool stuff! Although the issue I experienced was ultimately down to a minor error, I think the question can still serve to inform people about this particular problem. Thanks again!

Comment: @Kris As I noted, it's not actually a problem. It's completely understandable and expected behavior. It just so happens that the undocumented approach must use a different mechanism (more similar to `isa`) and works.

Comment: To be clear, the reason your first method fails is not quite (as @Suever suggests) because it doesn't have a default constructor; it's because it's trying to set a default value for the property which is an empty array of the Abstract class. This fails as it's not possible to create an empty array of an Abstract class, rather than because a default constructor is absent (it wouldn't be called in creating an empty array even if it existed). It's never been entirely clear to me why you shouldn't be able to create empty arrays of an Abstract class, but you can't. It would be useful if you could.